# Python Pandas alterates values in floating point

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have written a Python script which loads one or several csv files, concatenates them and writes the whole into a single new csv file. I have noticed that certain values are modified during this operation, being slightly incremented/decremented by very small values. As an example:

Original CSV:

```
Index SomeValue
0.000000    0.000
1.000000    0.000
2.000000    0.000
3.000000    0.000
4.000000    2.527
5.000000    0.000
```

Saved CSV:

```
Index SomeValue
0.0 0.0
1.0 0.0
2.0 0.0
3.0 0.0
4.0 2.5269999999999997
5.0 0.0
```

This looks like a full-scale error to me, but I don't know what causes it. The pandas core of my script, which is called in a loop, is:

```
l_tmpCsv_st = pd.read_csv(l_listElement_tc, sep='\t', index_col=0)
l_listOfCsvFiles_tst.append(l_tmpCsv_st)
# Fills in nan cells with the value "missing" to distinguish betweens a true nan and a missing value due to lacking padding
l_listOfCsvFiles_tst[-1] = l_listOfCsvFiles_tst[-1].fillna(value='missing')

# Concatenating csv file with previous ones
csvFusion = pd.concat([csvFusion, l_listOfCsvFiles_tst[-1]], axis=1)
```

And after the loop:

```
# Padding missing values of lower frequency files
csvFusion = csvFusion.fillna(method='pad')
# Determinating which columns need to be deleted (all "Unnamed" columns are panda-error results and need to be removed)
l_listColumnsToDelete_tst = [col for col in csvFusion.columns if 'Unnamed' in col]
# Dropping these columns
csvFusion.drop(l_listColumnsToDelete_tst, axis=1, inplace=True)
# Writing full stuff to file
csvFusion.to_csv(l_endFile_tc, sep='\t', decimal=',', na_rep='-')
```

The rest of my script is unrelated to pandas and would only harm readability, thus I have removed it from my copy/paste.

How could I avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance,

**Edition:**

It was indeed a floating point error. Rounding every value to a sufficient high digit solved it:

```
for col in csvFusion.columns:
    csvFusion[col] = csvFusion[col].round(15)
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: it's likely to do with float precision so the saved precision is larger than the display precision.

Comment: That totally looks like floating point precission. You know that in a commputer, not all numbers can be written exactly, rigth?

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: No error message. As @AnderBiguri pointed out, this is obviously a floating point precision issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need parameter `float_format` in [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), because floating point precission:

```
print df.to_csv(float_format='%.3f')
Index,SomeValue
0.000,0.000
1.000,0.000
2.000,0.000
3.000,0.000
4.000,2.527
5.000,0.000
```

I think you can use [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
 df['SomeValue'] = df['SomeValue'].round(3)
```

Comment: But, printing it wont change the fact that the number is probablyy the one shown in hos answer, not this one

Comment: I am storing several values of different sizes. I have provided an example with only three digits, but some values may have a higher precision, and I don't really like the idea of storing every number in %.15f, as it would bloat my end file.

Comment: Yes, understand. Is possible use [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html), e.g. `df['SomeValue'] = df['SomeValue'].round(3)`?

Comment: Wouldn't rounding these values cause the same issue, as the way these numbers are stored does not change?
I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, hard question. Maybe it can help, maybe not. But I have no other idea for this problem.

Comment: It worked. I just have to iterate over every columns. I'll edit my question to integrate this answer. Thanks a lot. :)